# Resetting Windows Vista Ultimate Password

Tags: windows-vista, passwords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows: How to reset the administrator password?](https://superuser.com/questions/5039/windows-how-to-reset-the-administrator-password)

I have received a laptop with Windows Vista Ultimate installed, but I never received the password to login, is there a way I can reset the password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's](http://4sysops.com/archives/three-ways-to-reset-a-windows-vista-admin-password/) a tutorial on how you can reset the password. There are about 4 ways listed on the page on how you can do this so it shouldn't be that difficult.