# Reset Vista password

Tags: windows-vista

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resetting Windows Vista Ultimate Password](https://superuser.com/questions/53144/resetting-windows-vista-ultimate-password)

Hi

Does anybody know how to gain access to a laptop running Windows Vista to re-set the password for the one and only user on the machine?

This is the windows password to log in rather than a BIOS password.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your password reset disk you created in the event that you forget your password.

Alternatively, check out #4 [here](http://4sysops.com/archives/three-ways-to-reset-a-windows-vista-admin-password/)

Answer (score 2):

While there are many options, the most versatile that I've used is [ntpasswd by Petter Nordhal-Hagen](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/).  The command line based interface can be daunting at first, but it's got a small footprint, loads quickly, and gets the job done.

I've been using it for years on systems from Windows 2000 to Windows 7 and I've never had a problem or failure.  That said, the level of complexity in the interface means that I wouldn't always trust my front line folks with it.

Comment: +1 I've used it for years as well. I've only ever had it fail once out of many dozen uses (BSOD after applying), and that was becuase it was one of the few times I tried to _change_ the password instead of just blanking it (I know, I know, they warn you against it ;) ).

Answer (score 0):

To add another way, just using the Vista DVD, you can replace utilman.exe and so get a cmd prompt without logging in to reset de password.

I posted a step by step video tutorial in english here:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ar-VoO9ogHc

I did it for a Windows Server 2008 DC, but it works for Vista and 2003 too