# Remove administrator password?

Tags: windows-xp, passwords, administrator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows: How to reset the administrator password?](https://superuser.com/questions/5039/windows-how-to-reset-the-administrator-password)

Is it possible to remove the administrator's password on an XP machine?
There is no option/link in user settings as there is for standard users.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the current password, it is easiest to login, change the password to blank and then logout.

If however you do not have the current password, but have administration over the machine,

1. Right click on `My Computer`.
2. Click on `Manage`.
3. Expand `System Tools > Local Users and Groups > Users`.
4. Right click on `Administrator`.
5. Click `Set Password`.

   [image]
6. At the next screen, click `Proceed`.
7. Simply press `OK`, without typing a password.

   [image]

This should work, so long as you do not have a complex or other password policy in place. If you do, and do not know how to remove it, please say and I will give you instructions.

Lastly, if you do not have local administrator access, I will probably question your intentions... but anyway, you will need a tool such as [Offline NT Password & Registry Editor](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) which will let you reset any password on the machine.

Of course, I need to say that setting a blank password really is not recommended, but I am guessing that you know what you are doing!