# XP Suddenly asking for password

Tags: windows, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove administrator password?](https://superuser.com/questions/95252/remove-administrator-password)

Is there any sane explanation for a client's Acer Aspire 1 netbook, running XP Home SP 2, suddenly starting to ask for a login password at boot?  He has a strict policy of not using passwords, and I removed his login password weeks ago.  The story is that suddenly this morning, for the first time, it is asking for a login password.

Comment: I once saw this after installing some optional .NET Framework components through Windows Update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this using the [Offline NT Password & Registry Editor](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/).  This tool is a lifesaver in situations like this.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you added another user. This will cause it to ask for a password. It might be a hidden user.

Try using (WIN+R)

```
control userpasswords2
```

To see if anything unusual is there, and you can also make sure the "users must enter username and password to use this computer" box is unchecked.

Comment: +1 hate this option for a security perspective, but correct way of doing it!

Comment: I can't use Win+R if I can't log on.