# Forgot Microsoft Virtual PC's password

Tags: passwords, microsoft-virtual-pc, windows-server-2003

I have a Microsoft Virtual PC on which I run Windows 2003 Server. I am right now in the system, but have forgotten the password. So, while I can continue to work now, if I were to lock the computer or shut it down, I am locked out.

Questions

1. How can I ensure that the Virtual PC automatic lock does not happen? (Giving me time to try and remember the password or for future users, to look up this question!)
2. How can I find out/reset my password?

Comment: Follow the same procedures you would use to reset a windows admin password for any other computer, just within the virtual machine. See ["Windows: How to reset the administrator password"](http://superuser.com/questions/5039/).

Comment: I have used the [Windows Password Recovery Corporation](http://windowspasswordrecovery.net) to help me recover my Vitual Windows password. It will also works for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Offline NT Password Reset](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) works pretty well, I used it to reset a Windows 7 password. Try it since 2003 server is based off the NT kernel. It's offline because you boot it as a live-CD, or bootable USB.

Since you run a VPC, get the boot CD, extract the download archive, and mount the CD in the VM so it boots off it.

Answer (score 1):

[Offline NT Password Reset](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) is a good suggestion to recover or reset the password.  However, to be able to use this tool you will need to boot directly into it, which poses a few problems depending on how your Virtual PC is set up.  Here are some instructions that worked for me (Windows 7 host / VPC).

Firstly, mount the ISO as the DVD drive:

- Ensure the VPC is powered down
- Download and unzip the ISO from the above website
- Right-click the VPC > Settings > DVD Drive > Browse to the ISO > OK

If **Integration Settings** are enabled on your VPC, you won't get a chance to boot into the BIOS to change the boot order, so do the following:

- Start the VPC
- Select Tools > Disable Integration Settings (the Windows password screen will appear)
- Select Action > Restart from the VPC menu

You should now be able to enter the BIOS:

- Start the VPC
- Hit DEL key before it boots up (you have to be quick)
- Set CD-ROM as the first boot device
- Close and save your BIOS settings

It should now boot into the Offline NT Password Reset tool.  The following options worked for me:

- Select drive (2)
- Confirm config folder (enter)
- Select part of registry (1)
- Edit passwords (1)
- Select user (enter username)
- Clear password (1)
- Quit and save changes (!, q, y, n)

You can now dismount the DVD Drive (Tools > Settings), then reboot the VPC.

When Windows boots up, select Enable Integration Features from the VPC Tools menu, and (optionally) set a new password for the user from the Control Panel.

Answer (score 0):

Start by going to `start` -> `run`,  then type `lusrmgr.msc`. Then change the administrators password. If you are not an administrator this won't work either, don't lock the screen because you won't have a fun time at that point!

Comment: OK. I posted this when I was about to hit the sack, so, I fell asleep after an exhaustive day at work and my computer is locked.

Answer (score 0):

You can run control userpasswords2 which will let you reset user passwords but only if you've got permissions.

Comment: @Kravlin: Thanks. The VPC just has one administrator login (and no other user login credentials) and it is the password that I have forgotten. Not a very intelligent thing to do, I completely agree!

Comment: Sorry. i didn't mean to sound pretentious. I just thought it might help.