# How to recover or remove password of Administrator

Tags: administrator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows: How to reset the administrator password?](https://superuser.com/questions/5039/windows-how-to-reset-the-administrator-password)

I have a PC with windows XP that administrator passowrd is forgeten and no other user account is created. How to set or recover or remove administrator password.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows: How to reset the administrator password?](http://superuser.com/questions/5039/windows-how-to-reset-the-administrator-password)

Answer (score 0):

I used [this](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) utility. Very easy to use, and works like a charm. :)

Answer (score 0):

[Petri IT Knowledgebase](http://www.petri.co.il/forgot_administrator_password.htm) has all the reliable/trusted solutions.

Greetings,
Marcel