# How do I reset a password for windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, passwords, password-management

I have a laptop with win-xp.
I forgot the password, how do I reset it?
I do not have the installation disk as this is a laptop that belongs to my employer (4 years ago) and was part of the network there.
I have no problem activating it, just forgot my password.

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/5039/windows-how-to-reset-the-administrator-password ; Answer can be found there.

Comment: @Shiki - none of those worked for me.

Comment: @Shiki - resetting administrator password is not what is asked here.

Comment: With the first app what Josh K linked , you can easily manipulate any account and I thought that will do the job, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Download and burn the Ultimate Boot CD [here](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/). Boot with the CD in the computer so it boots from the disk. It has a tool called "*Offline NT Password & Registry Editor*" that enables you to reset your password. It's totally free and works like a charm.

Comment: He said that doesn't work. That was my first shot since it was always fine here. Well, maybe ERD Commander will work.

Comment: Really? I have tried it before and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is with software like [ERD Commander](http://www.geekstogo.com/2009/01/17/erd-commander-free-trial-from-microsoft/) (used to be independent, now in MS's gamma of products ... I believe a free demo download is available, and it can be used for resetting passwords).

Answer (score 0):

The article [I Forgot My Administrator Password!](http://pubs.logicalexpressions.com/Pub0009/LPMArticle.asp?ID=305) details how one can reset any password in XP, provided that one has the XP boot CD and serial number. The method is detailed below:

1. Boot using the Windows XP CD (verify the bios set to boot from CD)
2. When the message arrives "Press any key to boot from cd", do it.
3. When you get to the Welcome to Setup screen, press ENTER to Setup Windows now
4. Licensing Agreement - Press F8 to accept.
5. The next screen should read something like "If one of the following Windows XP installations is damaged, Setup can try to repair it".
   Use the up and down arrow keys to select your XP installation (if you only have one, it should already be selected) and press R to begin the Repair process.
6. Let the Repair run. Setup will now check your disks and then start copying files which can take several minutes.
7. Shortly after the Copying Files stage, you will be required to reboot. (This will happen automatically: you will see a progress bar stating "Your computer will reboot in 15 seconds".)
8. During the reboot, do not make the mistake of “pressing any key” to boot from the CD again! Setup will resume automatically with the standard billboard screens and you will notice Installing Windows is highlighted.
9. Keep your eye on the lower left hand side of the screen and when you see the "Installing Devices" progress bar, press SHIFT + F10. This is the security hole! A command console will now open up giving you the potential for wide access to your system.
10. At the prompt, type NUSRMGR.CPL and press Enter. Voila! You have just gained graphical access to your User Accounts in the Control Panel.
11. Now simply pick the account you need to change and remove or change your password as you prefer. If you want to log on without having to enter your new password, you can type "control userpasswords2" at the prompt and choose to log on without being asked for password. After you’ve made your changes close the windows, exit the command box and continue on with the Repair (have your Product key handy).
12. Once the Repair is done, you will be able to log on with your new password (or without a password if you chose not to use one or if you chose not to be asked for a password). Your programs and personalized settings should remain intact.