# windows vist forgot username

Tags: windows-vista, operating-systems, windows-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows: How to reset the administrator password?](https://superuser.com/questions/5039/windows-how-to-reset-the-administrator-password)

In my windows vista i forgot my admin username and password ,

but i have gust username and password,

How to recover username and password ,

Else how to delete  admin username  and password  ,

Thanks

Comment: I think you shoud ask www.superuser.com, they're better than us at that kind of questions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need an offline SAM hive editor tool which can access your registry and retrieve or modify the information you are after. Superuser ought to be able to provide more information.