# Vm ware Lost Password Windows XP Virtual Machine

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine, passwords, vmware-player

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I reset the admin password of a Windows XP VM running in VMWare?](https://superuser.com/questions/179108/how-do-i-reset-the-admin-password-of-a-windows-xp-vm-running-in-vmware)

I have Win Xp as virtual machine, but I lost the admin password. Is it possible somehow to reset it?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/179108/how-do-i-reset-the-admin-password-of-a-windows-xp-vm-running-in-vmware

Answer (score 1):

Boot an ISO image of RIP (Rescue is Possible) and run chntpw after mounting the VM's hard disk. Change to the folder holding the SAM database and run chntpw to clear the password. Then reboot to Windows and log in as local admin with a blank password.

Or use one of the other bootable distros/disks that can clear the admin password.

Comment: Hi I have installed only VM WARE Player, I can mount vm hdd and set iso for CD-ROM, but it didnt boot from cd, it start always from vm hhd. Can you give me a advice how to do?

Comment: Have you done a websearch of any sort on this issue before coming here? These sorts of questions have been asked probably a half a billion times, and the answers given in similar numbers.