# remove laptop password

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows: How to reset the administrator password?](https://superuser.com/questions/5039/windows-how-to-reset-the-administrator-password)

I have a laptop and it has its password by fingerprint scanner with my brother's fingerprint and he has traveled abroad. I want to log in to the laptop but I can't. So what I can do to solve this problem?

Comment: Laptop, not labtop. Also, this is not the appropriate site for a question like this.

Comment: What kind of laptop?  This is a very relevant detail that you left out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try downloading [Ophcrack](http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/) and burning it to a CD/DVD. Boot from it and it will get the Windows passwords on the machine.

Basically, this will take the NTLM hashes and run them against rainbow tables trying to get the password.

If you can only login via fingerprint however, this will not work.

Answer (score -2):

This information is taken from the rather helpful chap over at [studyhat.blogspot.co.uk](http://studyhat.blogspot.com/2010/08/resetting-windows-password-using-linux.html) might help.

> **Resetting windows password using linux livecd**
>
> 1. Put the livecd in the cd/dvd drive and boot your windows machine from the livecd. (The application that we are going to use is `chntpw`.
>      In this example, we will be using fedora/ ubuntu livecd.)
> 2. Once booted, open the terminal and check for tool named `chntpw`. If not there, you can install it using:
>
>    $ yum install chntpw
>
>    - if you're using ubuntu live cd:
>
>    $ sudo apt-get install chntpw
> 3. After the tool is ready, mount the windows partition. Use "fdisk -lu" to check which partition should be mounted. To mount /dev/sda1 (assuming your windows partition is on /dev/sda1), use below command:
>
>    $ su mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
> 4. Find SAM file on the windows partition. Usually it is located in Windows/System32/config. Run the chntpw on the SAM file.
>
>    $ cd /mnt/Windows/System32/config
> 5. List all user in the SAM record
>
>    $ chntpw -l SAM
> 6. Interactively edit user credential
>
>    $ chntpw -i SAM
> 7. Follow the wizard of chntpw and clear administrator or any user's password that you want to access.
> 8. Save changes and restart machine. You can access the windows without password for administrator and users that you have cleared
>      their password. Make sure you take out the livecd, otherwise the
>      machine will boot into it instead of windows.

```
chntpw help:  

chntpw version 0.99.6 080526 (sixtyfour), (c) Petter N Hagen
chntpw: change password of a user in a NT/2k/XP/2k3/Vista SAM
file, or invoke registry editor.

chntpw [OPTIONS] [systemfile] [securityfile] [otherreghive] [...]
 -h    This message
 -u    Username to change, Administrator is default
 -l    list all users in SAM file
 -i    Interactive. List users (as -l) then ask for username to change
 -e    Registry editor. Now with full write support!
 -d    Enter buffer debugger instead (hex editor),
 -t    Trace. Show hexdump of structs/segments. (deprecated debug function)
 -v    Be a little more verbose (for debuging)
 -L    Write names of changed files to /tmp/changed
 -N    No allocation mode. Only (old style) same length overwrites possible
```

Comment: -1, same reason as on your [Bittorrent answer](http://superuser.com/questions/228865/bittorrent-client-for-centos-linux-command-line/228867#228867).

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here. Writing all your answers as blog posts is frowned upon...