# Lenovo Veriface log-in

Tags: windows-7, windows, lenovo-laptop, veriface

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How can reset Windows administrator password?](https://superuser.com/questions/5039/how-can-reset-windows-administrator-password)
>   [What can I do if I forgot my Windows password?](https://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-password)

i have a lenovo g460 laptop. my webcam has a lense problem- i can no longer use my veriface log-in and also i forgot my password. How can i or what should i do to access my laptop and files? is it possible to use an external USB webcam in replacement of the built-in cam in using veriface?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the [Offline NT password & Registry Editor tool](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) to reset your account's password.