# vista : how to recover/reset the password for Administrator user

Tags: windows-vista, passwords, administrator, password-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows: How to reset the administrator password?](https://superuser.com/questions/5039/windows-how-to-reset-the-administrator-password)

I have a sony vaio "windows vista home premium" laptop. I created an admin account(not called Administrator) and promptly forgot the password; However before I forgot the password, I created an ordinary account for my wife and she still remembers her a/c password. I can still get into the box through her account but I am unable to change the clock of the PC nor install any programs.

How can I reset my(administrator role) password or recover the password ? What are my options ? I have another Windows PC through which I can download software and burn

Thank you,

BR,
~A

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Vista Home Premium CD/DVD, you can reset the password the hard way by booting from the CD.  Don't use the recovery console but do Repair windows (screen after).  When it gets to the "Finishing installation..." part hit Shift+F10 to open a Command Prompt.  From there type "nusrmgr.cpl" to open up the Local Users box as an administrator.  From there you can change your password.

It's a pain, but it does work, and requires less "hacking".

Comment: I don't have one unfortunately. my laptop didn't come with one.