# Reset Windows 7 Admin Account without Admin Rights

Tags: windows-7, administrator, password-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows: How to reset the administrator password?](https://superuser.com/questions/5039/windows-how-to-reset-the-administrator-password)

On my Windows 7 computer, I created an administrator account "Admin" and then demoted my primary account to a standard user.

Now, Windows is not recognizing my password for the "admin" account and I can't get admin rights on my computer.

How can I either reset the password or make another admin account?

Comment: Windows XP admin password is trivial to bypass -- not so with Win 7 IMO.

Answer (score 0):

The supported way is to use [**Locksmith**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460909.aspx).

> Now, Windows is not recognizing my password for the "admin" account

aka you forgot it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tool that I used couple months ago for a similar reason:

http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/

> - This is a utility to reset the password of any user that has a valid
>     (local) account on your Windows
>     NT/2k/XP/Vista/Win7 etc system.
> - You do not need to know the old password to set a new one.
> - It works offline, that is, you have to shutdown your computer and boot off
>     a floppydisk or CD or another system.
> - Will detect and offer to unlock locked or disabled out user accounts!
> - There is also a registry editor and other registry utilities that works
>     under linux/unix, and can be used for
>     other things than password editing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are more comfortable using Ubuntu, or you have already got a live CD lying around somewhere the How-To-Geek has [a great blog post](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14369/change-or-reset-windows-password-from-a-ubuntu-live-cd/) on how to change or reset a Windows Account's password.