# How can I reset Windows Admin password?

Tags: windows-xp, user-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows: How to reset the administrator password?](https://superuser.com/questions/5039/windows-how-to-reset-the-administrator-password)

I am a student at NIIT. Someone (Student) has changed the Admin password of a computer. the PC have only 1 OS (WindowsXP) and has only 1 USER profile (NIIT) which is **System Administrator**.

What should be done to recover the account?
or Formatting is the last option.

Comment: If you're a student in the institute - why do you want to reset the Admin password ?

Comment: @Sathya: I know as a student no one going to tell me, but my teacher have faith in me, and called me for a solution

Comment: @Sathya: Sometimes a student _is_ the administrator...

Comment: Fair enough @grawity.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally tried this but supposedly the Ultimate Boot CD will help.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/reset-your-forgotten-password-the-easy-way-using-the-ultimate-boot-cd-for-windows/