# How do I reset the Windows password on an Acer Aspire One 753?

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, reboot, acer-aspire-one

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can reset Windows administrator password?](https://superuser.com/questions/5039/how-can-reset-windows-administrator-password)

I have an Acer Aspire One 753 notebook, but I don't know the password to the Windows 7 installation on it.

How do I reboot it back to default settings? It doesn't have a CD drive which would allow me to reinstall Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You could load windows 7 recovery mode with an USB stick holding the contents of recovery disc. But I am not sure whether you could revert the password back...

Answer (score -1):

Please read [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/change-your-forgotten-windows-password-with-the-linux-system-rescue-cd/), perhaps that'll help you. It uses a Linux distro from http://www.sysresccd.org/.

It is impossible to recreate here what the above web page shows.
It is full of screenshots.

Comment: I don't see why this got downvoted. I'd have posted a very similar answer.  I would have described it a bit more though.

Comment: the link which I posted above describes everything...

Comment: Link-only answers are a no-no due to link-rot (I didn't down-vote ;) ).  Please post pertinent information in your answer, using links for reference.