# Changed type of network and now can't log on

Tags: windows-xp

I have an old work computer at home using Windows XP Professional. The broadband was made secure and it wouldn't connect to the network anymore.

I was fiddling around and I went into a network icon on the control panel. I ran a wizard in the hope that it would automatically produce the network key the wireless set up was asking for.

I chose "Home computer not part of a network" instead of "Business networked computer" and restarted as instructed. Now the log on does not work.

How can I switch it back in the set up so that I can log on again?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have to [join your Windows domain](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sysdm_ident_join_domain.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply, but the first line of your link says- "To join a domain You must be logged on as an administrator" My problem is that I can't log on.

Comment: You have to use the local system administrator account that was used when the computer was initially installed. If you don't know the password for that account, [we can help you with that](http://superuser.com/questions/5039/how-can-reset-windows-administrator-password).