# Windows 7 turn off UAC from non-privelaged account

Tags: windows, windows-7, uac

i have a bit of a pickle.A few years ago i disabled administrator on my old windows 7 computer and created an admin account of my own. I also set a boot password. The problem is, now i can't access any account except guest, and i also can't access boot menu to boot any conventional cracking tools.

I also can't install anything, due to me being guest.

Is there any way i can disable UAC (user account control for Win7) from this non-privelaged account.

This probably isn't the right place to be posting non-coding related tech problems, but if you could give me a hand that would be great.

Thanks,

Comment: if you could just disable UAC as guest or normal user, what purpose would it serve? Malware would just start by doing that and presto, no more questions asked.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is either reset your BIOS password or take out the hard drive and put it on another computer. I would recommend resetting the BIOS password in case you need to do something else with it in future.

To reset the BIOS password, try any of the following:

- the motherboard's manual
- Google with your motherboard model
- provide more information in an edit to your question if you really can't find anything.

Once you have access to the hard drive from another operating system, there are [many ways](https://superuser.com/questions/5039/how-can-reset-windows-administrator-password) to reset the passwords in Windows.

---

Of course, you *do* own this computer so *there is no problem* with dismantling it to reset the BIOS password or remove the hard drive, *is there?*

---

And no, there is (should be) no way to bypass Windows' UAC or other security measures without having access to the hard drive from some other operating system. If you would bypass Windows' security from within the OS so easily, we have a pretty big problem.

Comment: Thanks, and yes, while it may sound suspicious i do own my computer. Is there any way to reset Boot passwords on a mac. (I know i said BIOS, not UEFI, but i though it would be possible to bypass UAC directly from windows

Comment: @JackRenshaw If it's a Mac, you should add that to your question (use the edit function). I don't have a Mac, so any help I could provide on that would be from Google anyway (such as [this search result](http://herouxapps.com/wordpress/archives/5348)).

Comment: Sure, thanks bob. i have a solution. I just remove the RAM and replace it with similar RAM, hold control-command-p, restart and replace origonal RAM. Simple, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nope. You can't.

Here are your options:

1. Take out the BIOS battery(a round button-like silver battery on motherboard). It will reset your BIOS password.
2. A lot of motherboards these days offer to choose boot device **without** going to BIOS menu.(e.g. F8 for ASUS motherboards.). Check if any such option is available to you.
3. Connect your HDD to other PC. And use that PC to reset your admin password(using those boot time tools).

Comment: Sure, thanks bob. i have a solution. I just remove the RAM and replace it with similar RAM, hold control-command-p, restart and replace origonal RAM. Simple, thanks

Comment: Of all the motherboards I've seen that offer a separate one-time boot selection menu, all of them required the BIOS password if one was set.

Comment: I have ASUS MoBo with that function.
And it does not ask me for password.
Unless ofcourse you set "user password", which does not seem to be Jack's case because he can start windows.