# Access Denied Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, passwords, login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can reset Windows administrator password?](https://superuser.com/questions/5039/how-can-reset-windows-administrator-password)

I just bought an large computer from Goodwill.

When Windows XP boots, there are three users

1. a name with no password or privileges
2. Guest
3. Network Operator/Administrator, which is password protected

I cannot delete or anything on the machine because it keeps coming up "Access Denied".  I have tried everything, including going to the registry but the machine is totally protected. **How I get administrator rights?**

Answer (score 0):

I would get a copy of [Kon boot](http://www.piotrbania.com/all/kon-boot/) and just reset the admin account password (or log into the admin account and create a new account.

Alternetively, just attach the hard drive to some other computer, run [ProduKey](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html) to recover the serial of XP, then re-install using that serial.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that goodwill did not format the drive before accepting/selling it...

Anyway: Format and reinstall or brute force with a Linux disk.