# How can i login in to windows again?

Tags: windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I reset the Windows administrator password?](https://superuser.com/questions/5039/how-do-i-reset-the-windows-administrator-password)

I am using windows service pack 2.

I locked my computer using password and updated my password just now. Now i try to login my windows system its tells "Invalid Password". It showing password error message. How can i reset password or how can i login again?

I have bundle of data inside my system. If i format my system then will lose data everything.

Any help much be Appreciated..

Can any one please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Restart your computer, and when you see the BIOS POST screen (basically, a few seconds after you hit the power button), alternate pressing Ctrl and F8.
2. When the Windows boot menu appears, select any of the safe modes offered.
3. On the login screen, you should see an “Administrator” login option. If you don’t, press Ctrl + Alt + Del twice and type in “Administrator” and leave the password area blank.
4. Windows should now start up, and you can go to the Control Panel and reset your user password.
5. You can also open Command Promt on any account (under Accessories) and then type "net user (your user name) password" with no parentheses and that automatically changes any accounts password to what you typed in for "password"

source : howto.wired.com/wiki/Reset_a_Windows_XP_Password (see other solutions there)

Answer (score 2):

You can try an crack it with the various XP login crackers available. Alternatively, if you have a second desktop or laptop computer you can plug the drive into a USB dongle to retrieve your data.

See this stack answer: [How do I reset the Windows XP Administrator password?](https://superuser.com/questions/5039/how-do-i-reset-the-windows-administrator-password)