# taskkill /f /im speedfan.exe cannot kill the task

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch-file

The following are used in a .bat file on Windows 10 Home Edition 64-bit.

```
taskkill /f /im notepad.exe
```

It can kill notepad.exe

```
taskkill /f /im speedfan.exe
```

It cannot kill speedfan.exe

C:\Program Files (x86)\SpeedFan\speedfan.exe

How can I kill speedfan.exe?

Comment: Works here on Windows 7. Did you get an error message?

Comment: It also worked when I was still using Windows 7. It doesn't work now on Windows 10, and I get no error message.

Comment: Have you tried the beta? [SpeedFan 4.52 beta 2](http://www.almico.com/sfbetaprogram.php)

Comment: I have tried SpeedFan 4.52 beta 2, which is even worse than  4.51.

Comment: Try  contacting the developer. He is pretty responsive to issues.

Comment: I have already told the developer, but I don't know whether he will deal with it.

Comment: No more ideas :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that because Speedfan requires special privileges in the system it is not run as your *current* user but runs under one of the administrator users and as a result only an elevated `taskkill` can kill it. I suspect that without administrator rights your batch file will also not be able to run Speedfan without a UAC prompt.

If you are wanting to do this *every time* your computer wakes then the best way will be via a Scheduled Task.  The benefit to this is that a scheduled task *can* run as an elevated user and so your batch file will be able to both kill *and* restart Speedfan without needing you to specifically do a "Run as Administrator" or click OK to a UAC elevation prompt.

It also means that your batch file will run every time your sleep event happens.

You can get to the Task Scheduler via `Control Panel` -> `System and Security` -> `Administrative Tools` -> `Task Scheduler`

Once there you should be able to select "Create Task" 
[image]

Then in that window select "Run with highest privileges":

[image]
(If that doesn't work then retry it as the "system" account using the "Change User or Group" button and searching on "system".)

Under the Trigger tab click "New" and change "Begin the task:" from "On a schedule" to "On an event"

The "wake from sleep" event appears to be emitted from [Kernel-Power and is Event ID 42](https://superuser.com/a/84453) (that page also lists Power-Troubleshooter and Event ID 1 as an alternative) so set up your trigger to the following

- Log: System
- Source: Kernel-power
- Event ID: 42

[image]

Click "OK" and then under the actions tab in the main task window you can add your batch file.

Hopefully that should allow you to run your batch file as an elevated user and thus kill and restart Speedfan properly from it.

Comment: It works, Mokubai, although I have had to use 'Kernel-Power' and '42' as 'Source' and 'Event ID' . Thanks a lot! How can I mark it as the best answer?

Comment: Glad you got the right trigger, I'll update my answer accordingly. It looks like you found the button to mark the answer as well, happy I could help.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to kill the process, I recommend you to use Process Hacker. It's like the taskmanager but can kill any process.
[Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/index.php)

Comment: No. I want speedfan.exe to be killed and restarted automatically each time after my computer wakes up from the sleep mode. It doesn't work properly unless it is restarted.

Comment: The first answer here may help you: http://superuser.com/questions/525961/access-denied-when-trying-to-end-a-process-on-windows-8

Comment: @ TeunissenStefan, I have downloaded PsExec v2.11. What should I do now?

Comment: CD into the PSTools folder, and use the command `psexec -s taskkill /im speedfan.exe /f`. Make sure to run it as administrator. Sorry for the delay, had to fix my tire

Comment: Sorry, what does 'CD' stand for?

Comment: Change Directory. For example `cd c:\folder`

Comment: Do you mean the command is cd c:\PSTools folder\psexec -s taskkill /im speedfan.exe /f

Comment: `cd c:\PSTools`
`psexec -s taskkill /im speedfan.exe /f`
So on 2 lines
Like this:
http://pastebin.com/gZCLjgGc