# Is it possible to install Windows XP driver files from a GNU/Linux live system?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers

I have a Windows XP machine with a **non-admin** account, and I would like to connect a scanner to it. Definitely, Windows XP has no built-in, generic driver for it. Due to non-admin account it's not possible to install the driver.

Now, I thought it could be possible to

1. Extract the necessary driver files (INF and SYS files etc.) from manufacturer's install software.
2. Start a GNU/Linux live system.
3. Mount the Windows XP partition.
4. Copy the driver files to the corresponding Windows directories (C:\Windows\System32\drivers etc.).

Would that be possible in principle or do I miss an important fact?

PS: When writing this question, I came to the conclusion that this approach is not very practicable. However, I would like to know if this would be possible in principle.

Comment: Why not ask your admin to install the driver?

Comment: It was a friend's question, and I don't know all the details. But I was interested if this approach is even possible.

Comment: @Benedikt - What you want is not possible.  You will need access to the `Administrator` account to install the driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When writing this question, I came to the conclusion that this approach is not very practicable.

True. You would not only need to extract the files to the right places and give then the right NTFS permissions. You would also need to edit the registry. Possible, but to be avoided if at all possible.

> However, I would like to know if this would be possible in principle.

In principle you can do it.

Just [resetting the admin password](https://superuser.com/questions/5039/how-do-i-reset-the-windows-administrator-password) and installing the driver is a lot easier though. Worst case you need to back up the file containing the old password so that you can restore it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the details. I have definitely forgotten the Windows registry thing.