# Make a admin account on a standard user account in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

I am on a standard user account and I want to change the admin's password but don't have the rights. Please help!

Comment: You can't.  You have to be logged into an `Administrator` level account to do this **in** Windows.  Since I believe this question is meant for malicious purposes I won't explain how to do this outside of Windows.

Comment: Related question: [How do I reset the Windows administrator password?](http://superuser.com/questions/5039/how-do-i-reset-the-windows-administrator-password)

Comment: Might not be for malicious purposes.  Sometimes you're given a PC and nobody remembers the admin password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load pwdump7 on it and use John the ripper to crack the hashes you acquire using dumpsec.

Here are the links to download the said tools:

PwDump7
http://www.tarasco.org/security/pwdump_7/‎

John the ripper 
http://www.openwall.com/john/

Good luck!

Of note

Depending on the security policy set forth by the domain administrators (assuming you're on a domain) you might not be able to install the tools. Give it a try, keep me posted.

Comment: I've lost my password to the admin though so PwDump7 won't work.

Comment: Are you a part of a domain?

Comment: No I'm on a normal laptop running windows 7

Comment: Perfect. If the laptop is not part of a domain and you are trying to reset the local admin password. Just use Ophcrack. You can find more information about it and download it from the following link:

http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/‎

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible. Administrator activities require administrative rights. Ask whoever has access to the administrator user, or if there is no one, prepare to reinstall windows.