# How to reset windows 7 password when USB ports are also not working?

Tags: windows-7, usb, passwords

There is a strange problem with my Windows 7 HP laptop, which is further complicated by the fact that I donot remember administrator password.  I was using the admin login through fingerprint reader, Digital Persona which has also stopped working.

Suddenly the USB ports have stopped working and not recognizing any external device.

For the past few days, this problem would occur after using laptop for the whole day but after rebooting, the USB ports and finger print reader would work ok.

Please suggest the best way to reset windows password and restore USB devices. Most of the articles on this problem suggest either downloading some app or modify hardware using Device manager, which I am not able to do without admin login. Niether can I reset the password using reset disk as USB ports are not working as per [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/5039/how-do-i-reset-the-windows-xp-administrator-password) here.

If it helps, the computer is dual boot, with Ubuntu 13.04. and can login on Windows with a user account.

Please help.

Comment: Do the USB ports work in Ubuntu? What about in Windows Safe-Mode?

Comment: Is the "user" account in the local administrators group?

Comment: There are tools to reset a Windows User's password.  I would use one of those to resolve your problem of being unable to log into the account.  The hardware problem will be harder to solve.  You boot to an optical disks instead of a bootable USB device.

Comment: USB port doesnt work in Ubuntu. The user account does not have admin privilege.

Comment: I did system restore to four days ago restore point before there was an automatic windows update. The finger print reader is working now. Any explanation why windows updates usually cause some problem ?

Answer (score 0):

- Inside of ubuntu, go to your windows partition
- Inside of windows\system32\ rename the file utilman.exe to utilman.exe.old
- Make a copy of cmd.exe and name it utilman.exe
- Reboot to windows
- Click on the blue icon on the bottom left of the login screen (the accessibility button)
- A command prompt will open
- Type "net user administrator *" without the quotes
- Set your new password
- Undo the renaming of files you did previously. Probably wont let you do that inside of windows.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not able to access the System32 files from Unbuntu. It doesnt show any files in that folder. Even with admin login, the renaming of file is not happening as it is saying that access is denied. Any workaround ?

Comment: Its odd that there are no files there. That entire folder is required for windows to boot. If you can boot from CD, you might try Trinity Rescue Kit at [TrinityHome.Org](http://trinityhome.org/Home/index.php?content=TRINITY_RESCUE_KIT_DOWNLOAD)

Comment: I thought those files must have been hidden as they are system files and maybe there is a different way to access them on Linux. Any thoughts on why windows updates cause errors with usb ports and finger print reader or how to avoid them?

Comment: They are system files, but linux shouldn't care too much. I've done it many times. Not sure on the windows update errors. Do the USB ports work outside of windows?

Also, if you have another computer available, you might be able to pull the hard disk out, install it as a secondary HDD, make the changes to the utilman file, then put it back in the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem a few months ago, and this link worked for me:

http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/ht/reset-password-windows-7.htm

Basically, you have to replace the utilman.exe utility (That button with accessibility options when you log-on to windows) on the Windows 7 System Repair option (using either the original Windows 7 CD, or a System Repair Disc burned with Windows 7. You can make one with any Windows 7 computer) with cmd.exe, and when you click the utilman.exe button on the logon screen, you have administrator access allowing you to change the password as answered by MagicGuitarist (I would have commented on his post instead of posting my own answer, but my reputation points do not allow me to).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. System repair disc seems useful. However, I dont know how to boot from cd if the usb ports are not working.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure I understand... if you think that your USB is not a hardware issue and instead a Windows Driver Issue, you should still be able to boot from a USB drive, correct?

Comment: What I meant is that I could not use any external device like a pendrive etc. All devices were said to have malfunctioned. So could not set or use password reset disk.