# window is not bringing Pin option

Tags: login

I am using Windows 8 And Ubuntu on a particular system, my Windows has two login options; PIN and password, little genius try to login in my absence but wasn't getting is right until the system refuse to bring the PIN option which I use often and can remember, its now bringing password that I can't remember, please how can I access the Windows password file from my Ubuntu and get it resolve, I DON'T WANT TO RELOAD MY PC, kindly help me please

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I reset the Windows XP Administrator password?](http://superuser.com/questions/5039/how-do-i-reset-the-windows-xp-administrator-password)

Answer (score 0):

You can boot to Safe Mode to access the Built-in Administrator account. From this fail-safe account, you can force-reset your account’s password.  Previous to Windows 8, accessing Safe Mode can be done by holding F8 while you starting the computer.

To reach safe mode on Windows 8, begin from the login screen. Click the Power Options icon, then hold down the Shift Key while you click the Restart option.
On the first screen that appears, select Troubleshoot, then select Advanced Options. Finally pick Startup Settings and click the Restart Button.
On the next screen, press the Number 4 Key to choose Safe Mode.

Now that you are in safe mode, you can use the built-in backup Administrator account to perform you necessary recovery. The built in Administrator account should not be used for any other purpose, or it won’t be available in situations like this when you need it.

At the login screen, click the arrow icon and select the Administrator account.
After Safe Mode starts, press WindowsKey-X to open Control Panel / User Accounts.
Select Manage another account and select the account you wish to change to an Administrator account. You can also use the Change Password option here to reset the other account’s password.
When you’re done, restart the computer normally.

source http://cmdrkeene.com/reset-forgotten-windows-password